Custom docker container on docker-compose cannot connect to influxdb container
I'm running a docker-compose with a custom container, influxdb and more.
All the containers are on the same network and can ping each other, but in the python code of my custom container I create a influxClient that outside of docker works fine, in the container gives me the errors copied below.
custom container code:
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WritePrecision, BucketRetentionRules
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS
import json


print("Starting writing test")

token = "xxxxxxxxx"
org = "rootyPi"
url = "http://influxdb:8086"
bucket = "user1"
client = InfluxDBClient(url=url, token=token)
write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
record = '{"measurement": "testDocker","fields": { "test": 1}}'
while True:
    print("Writing..")
    write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org=org, record=json.loads(record))

I get this error messages:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 198, in _new_conn
2024-04-20 20:06:45     sock = connection.create_connection(
2024-04-20 20:06:45            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-20 20:06:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
2024-04-20 20:06:45     raise err
2024-04-20 20:06:45   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
2024-04-20 20:06:45     sock.connect(sa)
2024-04-20 20:06:45 ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused



post your docker compose, or at least the relevant parts of it
